# slideshow cycle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help me run the cycle for my slideshow

This is the jQuery code I use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').cycle({
            fx: 'fade' 
            // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        });
    });
```

This is how I link the plugins

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    **<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>**
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

This is the html slideshow part

```
            <div class="slideshow">
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
                    <div id="slider">
                        <img src="images/slide1.jpg">
                        <img src="images/slide2.jpg">
                        <img src="images/slide3.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="controller" id="next"></
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you for the answer. I'm really not good in javascript.. :(

Comment: You should get rid of the first $(document).ready(function() { which  has no matching parenthesis and is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this first line in js code and try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Because you don't need two doc ready blocks and you don't have a closing tag for this either.

---

One more thing you can do is the stack order of the stylesheets and scripts has to be something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

You should load your stylesheets before js this is a good practice to have.

Comment: @user3619276 Its okay it happens, and i also got stuck at my early learnings of js/jQuery and other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You have used two     `$(document).ready(function() {` and one of them is not closed properly

Replace your code with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

           $('#slider').cycle({
               fx: 'fade' 
                // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
                    });
   });
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/fejuc/1/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)
I really suck when it's about javascript. :(